# Combining numbers in a sample based on preferences

Tags: r, sample, dice

So I'm writing a function for a board game and I have the sample "Rolls" which is given by:

```
Rolls <- sample(1:6, 6, replace = TRUE)
```

What I want is for my sample to prioritize certain numbers (if that makes sense), basically, let's say I want as many 4's as I can get from the sample. The options I have are to keep all the 4's I roll and to add up PAIRS of rolls to make more 4's. I might not have explained it well so here is an example:

Let's say I roll 3 4 2 1 1 1, I have a 4 that i want to keep (so i just leave it) but I also see that I have a 3 and 1 that I could take from the sample and add together to make another 4, so i want my code to do it, I want it to make as many 4's as possible. I also have a 2 and two 1's leftover that could make a 4, however, I'm not allowed to add up more than 2 numbers together so this should not be done. In the end my new sample should look like this: 4 2 1 1 4 (position of numbers is irrelevant)

I hope I've managed to explain my scenario well enough to understand, if any clarification is needed I can provide it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just for clarification: your final sample is `4 (=3+1)`, `2`, `1`, `1` and  `4(already from first "round")`. Is that correct? is missing one die. Right?

Comment: Correct, one of the 4's is the one we rolled and the other 4 is the result of 3+1

Comment: And yes, the final sample gets smaller (in length) based on how many additions were done since 2 numbers are used to make 1 new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work. I tried to write the functions with explanatory names and each step in a way that is not to hard to follow what it is doing.

the main idea is using `combn()` from built-in {utils} to get a data frame with possible combinations for "merging".

From the possible combinations, we can only merge 1 die once. (if you already merged the 1st and the 3rd, you should not be able to merge the 3rd and 4th, because the 3rd was already used). This step is done in `get_vec_of_dice_to_remove`. And then in the end we replace every 2 dice for one of the merging target.

I am sure that there are better and more efficient ways of doing it that I am not able to write. There are also other ways with much less steps (calls) but I prefer to leave it more explicit so that you can follow what is going on, and if you wish you can improve, remove some unnecessary steps or adapt the way you prefer.

(**tip**: if you want to follow step by step what goes on inside the function, use `debugonce(merge_dice_matching_nr)` to enter [debug mode](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) the next time you run the function. In debug mode you can *walk slowly through* the function and check each object while *inside* the function.)

```r
library(dplyr)

roll_dice <- function(nr_of_dice = 6) {
  sample(1:6, nr_of_dice, replace = TRUE)
}

get_data_frame_of_possible_combs <- function(throw, merging) {
  
  possible_combinations <- t(combn(throw, 2))
  sums_possible_combinations <- rowSums(possible_combinations)
  posit <- t(combn(x=1:length(throw), 2))
  df_res <- data.frame(possible_combinations,
                       sums_possible_combinations, 
                       match = (sums_possible_combinations == merging), 
                       posit) %>% 
    filter(match == TRUE)
  
  names(df_res) <- c("die_1", "die_2", "sums_possible", "match", "pos_d1", "pos_d2")
  return(df_res)
}

get_vec_of_dice_to_remove <- function(df) {
  vec_of_dice <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    row_of_df <- slice(df, 1)
    dice <- c(row_of_df$pos_d1, row_of_df$pos_d2)
    df <- df %>% filter( !(pos_d1 %in% dice | pos_d2 %in% dice) )
    
    vec_of_dice <- append(vec_of_dice, dice)
    
    if (nrow(df)==0) { break }
  }  
  return(vec_of_dice)
}


merge_dice_matching_nr <- function(throw, merging, merged_results_only=FALSE) {
  
  
  df_res <- get_data_frame_of_possible_combs(throw = throw, merging = merging)
  
  vec_to_remove <- get_vec_of_dice_to_remove(df_res)
  
  
  if (length(vec_to_remove)>0) {
    # if there is nothing to merge, return  results_merged as the original throw
    res_merged <- append(throw[-vec_to_remove], rep(merging, length(vec_to_remove)/2))  
  } else {
    res_merged <- throw
  }
  
  if (merged_results_only) {
    return(c(res_merged))
  }
  ret_list <- list("orignial_throw" = throw, 
                   "dice_posit_to_remove" = vec_to_remove,
                   "results_merged" = res_merged)
  
  return(ret_list)
}


set.seed(2)
(roll <- roll_dice()) %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 2)
#> $orignial_throw
#> [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1
#> 
#> $dice_posit_to_remove
#> [1] 4 6
#> 
#> $results_merged
#> [1] 5 6 6 5 2



roll %>%  
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 2, merged_results_only = T) %>%  
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 12, merged_results_only = T) %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 10, merged_results_only = T) %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 12, merged_results_only = T) %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 24, merged_results_only = T)
#> [1] 24


set.seed(2)
(roll <- roll_dice() )
#> [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1

roll %>% merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 2)
#> $orignial_throw
#> [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1
#> 
#> $dice_posit_to_remove
#> [1] 4 6
#> 
#> $results_merged
#> [1] 5 6 6 5 2
roll %>% merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 5)
#> $orignial_throw
#> [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1
#> 
#> $dice_posit_to_remove
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> $results_merged
#> numeric(0)
roll %>% merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 6)
#> $orignial_throw
#> [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1
#> 
#> $dice_posit_to_remove
#> [1] 1 4 5 6
#> 
#> $results_merged
#> [1] 6 6 6 6
```

### another implementation allowing for a numeric vector argument

this is another option that allows for a numeric vector input, so that it deals with one item at a time.

```
merge_dice_matching_nr <- function(throw, merging, merged_results_only=FALSE) {
  
  i_throw <- throw
  for (i in 1:length(merging)) {
    i_merging <- merging[i]
    df_res <- get_data_frame_of_possible_combs(throw = i_throw, merging = i_merging)
    
    vec_to_remove <- get_vec_of_dice_to_remove(df_res)
    
    
    if (length(vec_to_remove)>0) {
      # if there is nothing to merge, return  results_merged as the original throw
      res_merged <- append(i_throw[-vec_to_remove], rep(i_merging, length(vec_to_remove)/2))  
    } else {
      res_merged <- i_throw
    }
    i_throw <- res_merged
  } 
  
  if (merged_results_only) {
    return(c(res_merged))
  }
  ret_list <- list("original_throw" = throw, 
                   "dice_posit_to_remove" = vec_to_remove,
                   "results_merged" = res_merged)
  
  return(ret_list)
}


set.seed(2)
(roll <- roll_dice()) %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 2)

roll %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = c(2, 12, 10, 12, 24))

# $original_throw
# [1] 5 6 6 1 5 1

# $dice_posit_to_remove
# [1] 1 2

# $results_merged
# [1] 24
```

the other two functions remain the same.

#### answer to comment

this should work

```
set.seed(1212)
Rolls <- roll_dice()

Rolls
# [1] 2 1 5 4 6 4
Rolls <- Rolls %>% merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = 6, merged_results_only = T)
Rolls
# [1] 6 4 6 6
Rolls <- Rolls %>% merge_dice_matching_nr(5, merged_results_only = T)
Rolls
# [1] 6 4 6 6
```

Comment: I've tried it myself, works perfectly, this is really amazing, thank you so much

Comment: Just wondering if you know, otherwise I'll just mess around with the code and see if I can do it, using this code am I able to do something like this: Make as many 5's as possible, then if no more can be made (or none at all) see if any 6's can be made. Is this possible with this code?

Comment: a small modification was necessary. see edit answer

Comment: Does the order at the merging = c(2,12,10,12,24) matter? if 24 was first would it try merge to make 24 first then try to do 2, then 12, etc?

Comment: it only tries to merge 2 dice at a time, so the order matters. It would be quite complex to merge up to a number in any way because there are several possible ways merge. It is possible, of course, but will increase the complexity of the function quite a bit

Comment: no, that's fine, that's what I want, thanks

Comment: just one more question, the whole thing works but where do my new rolls get stored? Once I've got my new merged rolls how do I call them up so I can use them elsewhere in my code?

Comment: just assign the output to a new object `new_roll <- roll %>% 
  merge_dice_matching_nr(merging = c(2, 12, 10, 12, 24))`

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't seem to work as i want, I want to replace "Rolls" with my new values but when i try to do "Rolls<- roll %>%..." it doesn't work. I can do as you suggested and use "new_roll" then call it but I can only call it within the function, if I try to call "new_roll" anywhere else in my code it says it doesn't exist. Right now it only exists within my function

Comment: see last edit at end of answer. that should work. (works here)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, all works perfectly now